# Function for selecting option value from drop down based on variable value

Tags: php, html

Could somebody tell me a more optimal way of doing the following:

**HTML**

```
<select id="customer_country" name="customer_country"
        class="validate[required] input_styling"
        style="background: #FFFFFF;">
    <option value="">Please Select a Country</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan" >Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
  </select>
```

Given the above `<select>` element, how would I mark a specific option as `selected` based on whether it matches a variable value taken from a MYSQL statement, without writing the following lots of times

```
<option value = "Anguilla" <? if ($variable == "Anguilla") { echo 'selected'; } ?> </option>
<option value = "Antarctica" <? if ($variable == "Antarctica") { echo 'selected'; } ?> </option>
<option value = "Antigua and Barbuda" <? if ($variable == "Antigua and Barbuda") { echo 'selected'; } ?> </option>
<option value = "Argentina" <? if ($variable == "Argentina") { echo 'selected'; } ?> </option>
```

So the matching `option` will be marked as `selected` without having the write the above statement many, many times.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: would not be comfortable at first to keep the values in an array and make a loop?

Comment: @fefe - Interesting... could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

```
$selected = "Argentina";

foreach($array as $value){
  echo "<option value = '$value'";
  if($value == $selected){
    echo " selected='selected' ";
  }
  echo ">$value</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We have a function that prints `<option>` tags based on an array input.  It looks something like this.

```
function print_options(array $options, $selected = null) {
    foreach($options as $key=>$value) {
        $selected_attr = '';
        if ($selected == $key) {
            $selected_attr = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        echo "<option value=\"{$value}\" {$selected_attr}>{$value}</option>";
    }
}
```

Then you can just call it like this.

```
<select id="customer_country" name="customer_country" ...>
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <?php print_options(['afghanistan' => 'Afghanistan', 'aland_islands' => 'Åland Islands']) ?>
</select>
```

The function itself is a little smarter and handles escaping the strings and stuff, but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$countries = array(
    'Anguilla',
    'Antarctica',
    'Antigua and Barbuda',
    'Argentina',
);

foreach ($countries as $country) {
    $options[] = '<option value = "' . $country . '"' . ($country === $variable ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $country . '</option>';
}

$out = implode("\n", $options);
echo $out;
```

You can put that in a function or use it inline. An array with countries could probably be used for other stuff on the page as well.